# No ripples for MaterialCardView

Tags: android, material-design, material-components

Are there no ripples on the new `MaterialCardView`?

I used `CardView` with `android:clickable="true"` and `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` which worked fine but with the new `MaterialCardView` there are no ripples at all .

Other `View`s etc. keep working but I want my *card* to be clickable (with ripple as feedback).

Comment: Have you added a click listener on the card?

Comment: @ZUNJAE i tried it with and without a click-listener it it does not work (but either way it should make no difference).

Comment: I wasnt able to get `MaterialCardView` ripple working, so i set ripple effect to its content i.e constraintlayout

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a bug with `MaterialCardView`. It's overriding the foreground after it's created. I've filled a bug. It should be fixed to show a ripple if the card is clickable without needing to set the foreground.

If you can't wait for a fix you could use `CardView` from the support lib, or you could change your code to set the foreground drawable after the CardView has been inflated, or we would gladly accept a pull request! Relevant code at: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView.java. It can probably use https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/ripple/RippleUtils.java and a RippleDrawable for SDK >= 21.

Comment: Ok cool. Can you provide a link to the bug report so we can track it?

Comment: @cameron-ketcham a bug report link will be very welcome

Comment: @mFeinstein that bug was just one we were using to track internally. It's now been fixed, but not released yet: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/09673a5de798241860e5cecd051e0caa19397ca0

Comment: still not fixed

Comment: comment from the repo (2018-10-29): "We are releasing 1.1.0-alpha01 this week which will include this."

Comment: Still seems to be broken? Have a clickable focusable MaterialCardView and there's no ripple. 1.1.0-alpha07

Comment: @behelit you should be able to get a ripple if you add only android:clickable="true" to the `MaterialCardView`.

Comment: @CameronKetcham thanks, I think it ended up being due to the `style` parameter I was using (or not using)

Comment: I am using `alpha09` and `ripple` solved, But no `onclick` event in the adapter @hardysim

Comment: I'm using '1.2.0-alpha04' and it's working fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

In my case, It worked after adding `android:clickable="true"`, `android:focusable="true"` and `app:rippleColor="#cfd8dc"`  in `XML` file.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:rippleColor="#cfd8dc">
```

Answer (score -3):

Ripple effect is working now, but only if you add an OnClickListener on the CardView

Comment: Which version are you using (what's "now")?