# How to remove ripple effect from MaterialCardVew?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, materialcardview

How can I disable touch ripple effect of `MaterialCardView`?
Setting `clickable` attribute to `false` or playing with `foreground` and `background` attributes had no effect.

I'm using material support library version **1.1.0-alpha02**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No ripples for MaterialCardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675934/no-ripples-for-materialcardview)

Comment: @MartinZeitler This question is opposite! I've asked how to **remove** the ripple effect.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Only the `rippleColor` is a `styleable`:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**Note**: It doesn't remove the ripple effect from `<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` though.

Comment: In MaterialCardView there is no `rippleColor` attribute. So how are you remove it?  can you please explain?

Comment: @vikassingh there is. Maybe your dependency is old? try 1.1.0-beta07

Comment: doesnt work on android 13

Answer (score 2):

Just use this attribute in xml:
`app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"`

Or programatically in Kotlin:
`cardView.rippleColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT)`

Answer (score 1):

You also need clickable and focusable to false to remove the ripple effect

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false">
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do just using CSS like that:

```
.mdc-card__primary-action.card__primary-action.mdc-ripple-upgraded {
  &:hover,
  &:focus,
  &:active {
    &.mdc-card__primary-action::before,
    &.mdc-card__primary-action::after {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
      opacity: 0 !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is about android